# ElasticSearch: conditional sum

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I have records which contains a quantity column, which can be negative or positive. I want to calculate the total quantity where the values are positive.

I know I can calculate the sum using `elastic.NewSumAggregation().Field("quantity")`, but I'm not sure about how to include only the positive rows.

Any body can help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding working example

**Index sample docs**

```
{
    "quantity": 10
}

{
    "quantity": -10
}

{
    "quantity": 25
}

{
    "quantity": -25
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "quantity": {. // filter only for positive quantity.
                "gte": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "quantity": {
            "sum": {
                "field": "quantity"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And search result**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "65188985",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "quantity": 10
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "65188985",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "quantity": 25
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "aggregations": { // note this aggregation part, which is sum of 10 and 25.
        "quantity": {
            "value": 35.0
        }
    }
```

If you want to extract only aggregation part, gives `size=0` for query part.

```
{
    "size":0,
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "quantity": {
                "gte": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "quantity": {
            "sum": {
                "field": "quantity"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Above will output below response**

```
 "aggregations": {
        "quantity": {
            "value": 35.0
        }
    }
```